# if $f(1/n)$ is real function,show that $f(x)\in R,x\in R$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)$ is Entire function
if $f(\dfrac{1}{n})$ is real function for any $n=1,2,\cdots,$,show that
$$f(x)\in R,\forall x\in R$$

I think we can show that
$\overline{f(z)}$ is also Entire function? Thank you

Comment: Hello,sorry,can see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Answer (score 2):

Unless $f$ is constant, the function $z \mapsto \overline{f(z)}$ will not be holomorphic.

But, for an entire function $f$, the function $g\colon z \mapsto \overline{f\bigl(\overline{z}\bigr)}$ is again an entire function.

By assumption, we have $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Can you conclude that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?